# how to expose a datatable to asp.net webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a datatable that is populated on page load :

```
DataTable dtWIPRoute;
```

I've then got a webmethod on the same aspx page to process an ajax call:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string myWebMethod(string ID, int POS, string TXT, int OPOS)
    {
        //if(ID == "4" )
        //{
        //    return "changed";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    return "failed";
        //}
        return OPOS.ToString() + ',' + POS.ToString();
    }
```

How do I expose the datatable to the webmethod please as I need to change the data within it dependant on what the jquery returns.

Cheers.

Comment: Refractor your the page load method, so that the data table loading is in a function.  Then call this function in your web method, prior to processing.

Comment: store the datatable in a session?

Comment: `WebMethod` is outside of the normal page request lifecycle. So you'll need to store it where they can both access it, such as Session. However, you really shouldn't be creating new `WebMethods` anyways, as they're [no longer supported](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/). Instead, you should use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: You could instead use an HttpHandler that implements the (marker-only) interface `IRequiresSessionState`. That way your handler can access the session state of your web app.